# How to feed a Pleco in a community tank?

Tags: aquarium, fish, feeding, community-aquarium, pleco

I got a Pleco to control brown algae in my community tank (3 female Bettas, 1 Pleco).

At this point, the algae is largely controlled, which leaves another problem: I need to increase supplemental feeding. However, I'm having a problem with the Betta fish eating the algae wafers (which isn't good food for them, and means that the Pleco doesn't get it).

How do I feed the Pleco without having the Betta fish eat all the food?

Comment: You can try feeding at night when the lights are off, or feeding some rapeseed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar situation before, and added a simple "shelter" to tuck the Pleco food under. Most fish, and I suspect bettas as well, won't bother swimming under a low structure on the substrate of your tank. My Plecos took to sliding along the floor to fit under the structure and feed. It probably doesn't need to be so low that the Plecos are squeezing, but enough the bettas aren't inclined to try and get under it.

This may not work with bettas, or in your tank, but I managed to even keep some wrasse at bay by doing this.